# The "Object not found" is not visible

Tags: r

So I've been trying for a while now to successfully plot a custom 2D Latitude x Longitude map from a GAM I created (with package mgcv).  However, I am encountering a problem.  After I enter the following command:

```
myvis.gam(llgam, view = c("lat","long"), n.grid = 100,
          plot.type = "contour", color = "jet", contour.col = "",
          too.far = .05)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in myvis.gam(llgam, view = c("lat", "long"), n.grid = 100, plot.type = "contour",  : 
object 'v' not found
```

The reason for my confusion from this error is that there is no "v" object present in the script.  I've never seen this before.  Usually, if it states that object "x" is not found, object "x" is used in the script entered prior.

Any ideas?  (What does it mean when it gives an error for an object that is not shown in the entered script?)

NOTE: The "myvis.gam" function is custom-made.  It is essentially an edited version of the "vis.gam" script (package mgcv) and follows the same "usage" base:

```
vis.gam(x,view = NULL, cond = list(), n.grid = 30, too.far = 0, col = NA,
        color = "heat", contour.col = NULL, se = -1, type = "link",
        plot.type = "persp", zlim = NULL, nCol = 50, ...)
```

It also uses the same arguments.

If anyone wants the full code for this function, I am happy to give it.  It's just lengthy.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: Run `traceback()` to see the call tree before the error - this can help you figure out where the problem is. I assume you've tested `myvis.gam` on other models? Can you change one thing at a time in your input model to see where it breaks as you move from a working input to the broken input?

Comment: I just found another code online for visualizing a GAM and it seems to work fine.  Must be an error in the source code of the function then.  Anyway, thank you for your help!